# Append on condition

Tags: python, append

I'm going to write a program that takes some lines and translates them into one line but unfortunately, I have a problem with appending uncommon elements. this is what I've done so far:

```
List_of_sentences = []
for line in range(int(input())):
    List_of_sentences.append(input().strip().split())

Sample_sentence = input().split()

Final_list = []

for lists in List_of_sentences:
    for elements in Sample_sentence:
        if elements in lists:
            Final_list.append(lists[0])
        else:
            Final_list.append(elements)
            
print(' '.join(Final_list))
```

for example, consider these two lists:

```
List_of_sentences = [['man', 'I', 'je', 'ich'], ['kheili', 'very', 'très', 'sehr'], ['alaghemand', 'interested', 'intéressé', 'interessiert'], ['barnamenevisi', 'programming', 'laprogrammation', 'Programmierung']]

Sample_sentence = ['I', 'am', 'very', 'interested', 'in', 'programming']
```

it has to return this:

```
man am kheili alaghemand in barnamenevisi
```

but instead:

```
man kheili alaghemand barnamenevisi
```

my problem is with else part

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: For me, your code produces something like "man am very interested in programming I am kheili interested in programming I am very alaghemand in programming I am very interested in barnamenevisi..." and so on.

Comment: yes it does and I want sth like this: man am kheili alaghemand in barnamenevisi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop seems little bit messed up. It should be like this order

```py
List_of_sentences = []
for line in range(int(input())):
    List_of_sentences.append(input().strip().split())

Sample_sentence = input().split()

Final_list = []

for elements in Sample_sentence: #this for loop should be first
    var = None
    for lists in List_of_sentences: # this for loop should be second
        if elements in lists:
            #Final_list.append(lists[0])
            var = lists[0]
            break
    Final_list.append(var if var else elements)
            
print(' '.join(Final_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have tried and it works:

```
List_of_sentences = [
    ['man', 'I', 'je', 'ich'], 
    ['kheili', 'very', 'très', 'sehr'], 
    ['alaghemand', 'interested', 'intéressé', 'interessiert'], 
    ['barnamenevisi', 'programming', 'laprogrammation', 'Programmierung']
]
Sample_sentence = ['I', 'am', 'very', 'interested', 'in', 'programming']
Final_list = []

for elements in Sample_sentence:
    found = False
    for lists in List_of_sentences:
        if elements in lists:
            Final_list.append(lists[0])
            found = True
    if not found:
        Final_list.append(elements)

print(' '.join(Final_list))
```

The problem with your code is that it will always add an element if it isn't found instead of adding it once and proceeding with next element

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
for elements in Sample_sentence: # since you need to check for elements in the sample sentence in all lists, this should be the outer loop
    present = False
    for lists in List_of_sentences:
        if elements in lists:
            Final_list.append(lists[0])
            present = True
    if not present:
        Final_list.append(elements)
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
for word in Sample_sentence:
    append = False
    for list in List_of_sentences:
        for translation in list:
            if (translation == word):
                Final_list.append(list[0])
                append = True
    if (not append):
        Final_list.append(word)
            
print(' '.join(Final_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is so because you are iterating over each list and for each list, you are iterating over each element in the sample sentence, therefore, first, it will search if any of the element from the sample sentence matches in the first list or not ("I" will match), then it will insert the first element of the list i.e "man" in the final list.
for the second list "very" will match, therefore, it will insert the first element of the second list i.e "kheili" in the final list.
Therefore, the final list would be like: ["man", "kheili" .... ], which is what you got.
This explains the problem you are encountering.